# Where to specify "json", when using $.post with promises

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback

What is the correct way to use promises with $.post call, while still specifying datatype "json" ?

I did some tests but get results I do not fully understand.

1)
This works, handling data ONLY within a function in $.post:

```
$.post( "foo.net/api", {a: "this", b: "that"}, function(data){
  $('body').html(data);
}, "json");
```

2)
This returns wrongly formatted data, handling data ONLY within a function in .done:

```
$.post( "foo.net/api", {a: "this", b: "that"}, "json")

.done(function(data){
  $('body').html(data);
});
```

3)
This also seems to work, handling data within post AND then within .done:

```
$.post( "foo.net/api", {a: "this", b: "that"}, function(data){
  $('body').html(data);
}, "json")

.done(function(data){
  $('body').append(data);
};
```

4)
BIZARRELY (to me at least) this also works, having an empty function within post, AND then handling data within done:

```
$.post( "foo.net/api", {a: "this", b: "that"}, function(){
  // empty function
}, "json")

.done(function(data){
  $('body').html(data);
};
```

**This last test puzzles me.** Why would an empty function within post, allows .done to access and use the json datatype? Whereas no function (as in the second example) leaves .done with an unformatted output?

So how do I specify the "json" datatype properly?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The data type would be the last parameter of the post function

```
$.post( "test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" }, 'json')
  .done(function( data ) {
    // do something with response data
  })
  .always(function() {
    // do something afterwards
  });
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, that does not work for me in specifying json type. I get the same result with and without 'json' at the end.

Comment: Additionally I mistakenly added a ';' after the first .done(), which you reproduced, and should not be there. I believe the ';' goes after the last promise. Even more, there seems to be the possibility to use more than one .done() , anyway 'json' does not seem to work for me as I said. May it be my error?

Comment: I simplified the question.